# Use CTRL key from the variable in map-<expr>

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings

I have a variable with a "key" in vim notation, `<C-j>`. How can I use it in `<expr>` mapping?

```
let g:key = "<C-j>"
inoremap <expr> <C-j> '\' .. g:key

" inserts \<C-j> instead of newline
```

The mapping I get from redirecting `imap` and extracting the `<C-j>` out of it, so I can't use `let g:key = "\<C-j>"`.

Comment: Edit: `feedkeys()` won't work because it also requires `"\<C-j>"`-style strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need backslash in map command. Simply

```
let g:key = "\<C-j>"
inoremap <expr><C-j> g:key
```

UPD. It looks as if you want `:h nvim_replace_termcodes()` function available in Neovim. There's no direct counterpart in Vim, but you can write your own (incomplete?) implementation:

```
function! Replace_termcodes(str) abort
    return a:str->substitute('<', '\\<', 'g')->printf('"%s"')->eval()
endfunction
```

Comment: The example in the question is simplified version of what I have. Basically I have only `<C-j>` in a variable I parsed out from output of `imap`. And I want to reuse it as a fallback in my `expr` mapping.

Comment: imagine you have got `'<C-j>'` as an input into `SomeFunction(key)` and that function is in `<expr>` mapping, returning some key sequences plus `"\<C-j>"`

Comment: @MaximKim Actually it looks to me as a questionable design, but I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [maparg()](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#maparg%28%29) function:

```
:echo maparg("<C-j>", 'i', 0, 1)
{'lnum': 0, 'script': 0, 'mode': 'i', 'silent': 0, 'buffer': 0, 'noremap': 1, 'lhs': '<C-J>', 'lhsraw': '<80><fc>^DJ', 'nowait': 0, 'expr': 1, 'sid': 0, 'rhs': '"\<C-j>"', 'lhsrawalt': '
', 'scriptversion': 0}
```

You can use the 'rhs' item from the returned dictionary.